# Getting Good Google PageRank

Tags: seo, google-search, pagerank

In SEO people talk a lot about Google [PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank). It's kind of a catch 22 because until your site is actually big and you don't really need search engines as much, it's unlikely that big sites will link to you and increase your PageRank!

I've been told that it's easiest to simply get a couple high quality links to point to a site to raise it's PageRank. I've also been told that there are certain Open Directories like dmoz.org that Google pays special attention to (since they're human managed links). Can anyone speak to the validity of this or suggest another site/technique to increase a site's PageRank?

Comment: Why is that an incorrect requirement? High page rank = $ for a lot of websites.

Comment: Because page rank is not a software developer requirement, it should be an SEO expert requirement or something similar. The requirement is more akin to a system's analyst job than a software dev's

Comment: SEO can affect the way a site is designed especially the URL strategy and accessbility requirement to a minor extent for the bot. If it's not included as a requirement if often comes up right at the end of the project.

Comment: Edward, you've got a point there. I still think it should be part of the system analysts' job, though. Admitting that, I guess that means I concede that it is software development related. :D

Comment: I understand that this question been closed because it's off topic, however it was asked before the existence of other stack exchanges. Shouldn't it just be migrated to webmasters.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Have great content

Nothing helps your google rank more than having **content** or offering a service people are interested in. If your web site is better than the competition and solves a real need you will naturally generate more traffic and inbound links.

### Keep your content fresh

### Use friendly url's that contain keywords

**Good**: http://cars.com/products/cars/ford/focus/

**Bad**: http://cars.com/p?id=1232

### Make sure the page title is relevant and well constructed

**For example**: Buy A House In France :. Property Purchasing in France

### Use a domain name that describes your site

**Good**: http://cars.com/

**Bad**: http://somerandomunrelateddomainname.com/

**Example**
Type car into Google, out of the top 5 links all 4 have car in the domain: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=car

### Make it accessible

Make sure people can read your content. This includes a variety of different audiences

- People with disabilities: Sight, motor, cognitive disabilities etc..
- Search bots

  In particular make sure search bots can read every single relevant page on your site. Quite often search bots get blocked by the use of **javascript** to link between pages or the use of frames / **flash** / **silverlight**. One easy way to do this is have a site map page that gives access to the whole site, dividing it into categories / sub categories etc..
- Down level browsers

### Submit your site map automatically

Most search engines allow you to submit a list of pages on your site including when they were last updated.

Google: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/docs/en/about.html

### Inbound links

Generate as much buzz about your website as possible, to increase the likely hood of people linking to you. Blog / podcast about your website if appropriate. List it in online directories (if appropriate).

### References

- [Google Search Engine Ranking Factors, by an SEO company](http://www.seomoz.org/article/search-ranking-factors)
- [Creating a Google-friendly site: Best practices](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/topic.py?topic=8522%3E)
- [Wikipedia - Search engine optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization)

Comment: Addendum: Why does great content and friendly urls help? People will link to it which will lead to higher page rank.

Comment: @Spoike - Also, friendly URLs are more likely to be indexed by search engines, therefore allowing more hits to your site if the search engine can find the page(s) a user searched on.

Content can be ranked by quality and quantity to other site's content in the same categories, so make sure content is relevant to the site's purpose. If you have a site about cars and it talks more about bikini car models, it's not so much about cars after all and will be ranked lower in the car category, allowing users to get the most relevant results for "car" rather than bikinis models.

Answer (score 7):

Good content.

Update it often.

Read and digest everything at [Creating a Google-friendly site: Best practices](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/topic.py?topic=8522).

Be active on the web. Comment in blogs, correspond genuinely with people, in email, im, twitter.

I'm not too sure about the domain name. Wikipedia? What does that mean? Mozilla? What word is that? Google? Was a typo. Yahoo? Sounds like that chocolate drink Yoohoo.

Trying to keyword the domain name shoehorns you anyway. And it can be construed as a SEO technique in the future (if it isn't already!)

Answer all email. Answer blog comments. Be nice and helpful.

Go watch [garyvee](http://twitter.com/garyvee)'s [Better Than Zero](http://garyvaynerchuk.com/2008/08/12/better-than-zero/). That'll motivate you.

Answer (score 3):

If it's appropriate, having a blog is a good way of keeping content fresh, especially if you post often. A CMS would be handy too, as it reduces the friction of updating. The best way would be user-generated content, as other people make your site bigger and updated, and they may well link to their content from their other sites.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't want you to have to engineer your site specifically to get a good PageRank. Having popular content and a well designed website should naturally get you the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

A easy trick is to use

Google webmaster tool  https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools

And you can generate a sitemap using  http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Then, don't miss to use www.google.com/analytics/

And be careful, most SEO guides are not correct, playing fair is not always the good approach. For example,everyone says that spamming .edu sites is bad and ineffective but it is effective.